# PHP. Как найти наименование всех родителей по id элемента в дереве?

Tags: php, алгоритм, поиск, дерево

Есть дерево подобного вида - массивы и объекты. Вложенность может быть любой глубины. Задача по имеющемуся идентификатору (Ид) найти наименование элемента и всех его родителей.

[image: Пример участка дерева]

Comment: Надо прочитать все и составить массив ключ => родительский элемент.

Comment: Можно еще читать XML с помощью XPath и использовать `::parent` в ноде, найденной по ID

Comment: Алгоритм решения вам здесь никто выкладывать не будет это затратно по времени, а вот подсказать помогут. Я бы решил это при помощи рекурсии и двух функций is_array()  и если is_object, то get_object_vars()